# How to read in and separate separated integers such as "100_4_1 - 15"

Tags: c++, parsing, file-io

This is really easy in some languages, not so easy in others.  I can't quite get it for C++.  I'm reading in a file with thousands of lines of the format in the question title, and reading the file over and over again thousands of times.

Basically, I have some integers in mind in my program, say "`100, 4, 1`", and I want to look up in a text file what the last digit in the sequence is, so the line might be "`100_4_1 - 15`", i want to get the `15`. How can this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> some integers in mind in my program, say "100, 4, 1", 
>   "100_4_1 - 15", i want to get the 15

```
struct Key
{
    int a_, b_, c_;
    Key(int a, int b, int c) : a_(a), b_(b), c_(c) { }
    bool operator<(const Key& rhs) const
    {
        return a_ < rhs.a_ ||
               a_ == rhs.a_ && b_ < rhs.b_ ||
               a_ == rhs.a_ && b_ == rhs.b_ && c_ < rhs.c_;
    }
};

typedef std::map<Key, int> Lookup_Table;
Lookup lookup_table;

if (std::ifstream if("filename.txt"))
{
    int a, b, c;
    char ignore_char;
    int number;
    while (if >> a >> ignore_char >> b >> ignore_char >> c >> ignore_char >> number)
        lookup_table[Key(a, b, c)] = number;
}
else
{
    std::cerr << "can't read input file...\n";
    exit(1);
}

// to find something:
Lookup_Table::const_iterator i = lookup_table.find(Key(x, y, z));
if (i != lookup_table.end())
{
    // found... value accessible using *i...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This would depend on the numbers themselves... Is this 10,000 like file, is just one fixed file?

If it was, and for example, and it had 3 index integers, and an integer that you need to look-up, it would be simple to just load it all in memory and look it up whenever needed.

in C/C++ a simple array of structs would do it well, for example:

```
#define NUMELEMENTS 1000

struct Element {
    int x;
    int y;
    int z;
    int v;
};

class Elements{
    elements Element[NUMELEMENTS];
    public:
    int findElement(int,int,int);
    void loadElements;

} E;
```

I'd then use E.FindElement(100,4,1) and get 15.

loadElements would load the file by reading in line by line and separating the numbers (I would read a string, remove spaces, unify the dashes and underscores and get the numbers between the separators.

findElement would just loop through the elements... for 10k elements i wouldn't worry about optimizing unless this was running on an embedded device.

Comment: Thanks, so loading it into main memory would be faster.  The main part of the question is reading it in though :)